# NextJS refused to execute script from fetched resource because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: typescript, azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service

I'm using nextjs:`14.1.0` react:`^18` with typescript:`5.3.3`

and post `npm run build` command build, I'm getting this document sample -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
        <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/77788e7958239d57.css" crossorigin="" data-precedence="next"/>
        <link rel="preload" as="script" fetchPriority="low" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-6f58ff0e804dbd64.js" crossorigin=""/>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/fd9d1056-014bdae05f6da747.js" async="" crossorigin=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/69-855792fd7a371558.js" async="" crossorigin=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app-38e544f4272c039c.js" async="" crossorigin=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/899-4ea934008c86dde4.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/370-81c677ced3d8668d.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/198-c1847edf924a8a70.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/244-7d607b06b949a266.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/107-3ee303d218f91d93.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/964-fe494fec62b2f455.js" async=""></script>
```

In localhost, its working fine, but in server it's been failing with following error-

> Refused to execute script from
> 'https://abc.domain/_next/static/chunks/webpack-6f58ff0e804dbd64.js'
> because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type
> checking is enabled.

and others tags are also failing where attribute `crossorigin` is available, Hence I'm not using SSR, but just relied on static build pages.

Also, how could I attached `<script type="text/javascript" src="./webpack-6f58ff0e804dbd64.js" crossorigin="" />`

as I'm using `Next.js` latest recent version, is there any config available to do above required stuffs.